# What could cause this black shape on the photo?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, spots

[image: is-my-kid-possessed]

This is the only photo that looks like this, others taken before or after look fine, so I don't think it's dust or oil in the camera or on the sensor. Photo was taken during summer months, so could it be a bug that flew in the frame at just the right time? Leaning towards no, since it appears to be roughly square in shape but oriented like a diamond.

Camera is Canon DS126071 (Canon EOS Rebel XT 8MP DSLR)

ISO - 1600

Shot - 1/640 sec. f/16 22mm

Edit - let me be absolutely clear, I mean the giant black square over the subject's face, that wasn't intentionally put there to mask his identity before posting.

Comment: seems like you tried to photograph [Silence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silence_(Doctor_Who))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I once noticed what looked like a very large dust goober on a few images as I was shooting an event. It was with a camera that had the same lens attached to it for at least several weeks. Even more curiously, it seemed to be moving around between shots.

Just before I pulled the lens off to blow off the sensor in the field (something I would normally *never* do), I noticed a medium sized spider spinning a web in the lens hood.

In the case of the spider, it was longer than it was wide and all squiggly. Your example looks kind of like one of Roger Cicala's little 'post-it note' squares stuck to the back element of a lens in [this lensrentals.com blog entry](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2011/08/the-apocalypse-of-lens-dust/).

[image]

[image]

My guess is that some kind of insect more square in shape flew past the front of your lens at just the right moment and was captured in your frame.

Maybe it was a dead leaf from the abundant vegetation where you were.

It could even have been a piece of litter blowing in the wind.

Or aliens.

Comment: This is as creepy as the question itself. :o)